# Java: Reloading in-memory cache (like Guava) to get new entries written to Database every 5 mins

Tags: caching, amazon-dynamodb, guava, preload

I have a use case, where I am caching static(unchangeable) records from **DynamoDB** to an in-memory cache. Suppose I loaded my cache at application start with all records from DynamoDB. If I want to **periodically** reload my cache in order to get the new records written to DynamoDB, is there a way where I can create reloading caching strategy where I query the DynamoDB only to give me the records after a particular timestamp? 
**My goal is to avoid unnecessary DynamoDB reads during cache reloading for the records I already have in my cache.**

Would really appreciate if someone can share views on this. Open to discuss if I need to use a different in-memory cache than Guava which would be better for this use case. thanks

Comment: if you set a timestamp for every record, or hook the update and insert functions and remember the changed tables / rows then its possible

Comment: I do have a timestamp for every record in the DynamoDB. There will no update queries to my DB, there will be inserts and I need a mechanism to get inserts from the last 5 mins (reason: I am not updating my cache when there is a cache miss, so I need a mechanism to get recent records to my cache).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below architecture.

1. Have a lambda function listening to dynamodbstreams.
2. Send sns notification on every insert. (since data is never updated as par your question)
3. application listens to sns notification and updates the record in your cache.

[image]

This solution has few issues like

1. Updates are real time than 5 mins delay. which is better considering there wont be spike of reads on your db.
2. you can not send full record in sns notification considering dynamodb max size is 400kb, but for sns it is 256 KB.
3. Hydrating state for a new instance is still tricky. (you can try to lazily load entries rather than creating complete state from start.

If you don't have very strong latency requirements, rather than keeping state in so many application instances, you can have single cache instance with slave. Following the above architecture.